# Gitlab CI/CD for java spring maven application

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to Gitlab CI/CD and would like to understand how to use it correctly.
I have the following project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2hKy.png)

and the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javasampleapproach</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-rest-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringRestMySQL</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot - REST -MySQL</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can you help me please configure .gitlab-ci.yml and CI Lint on GitLab in order to test correctly build, test and deploy?

When I added default pipeline on GitLab it always fails in test stage with the following error:

```
    Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

        Property: driverclassname
        Value: org.postgresql.Driver
        Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
        Reason: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

    Action:

    Update your application's configuration

2018-10-11 22:55:34.413 ERROR 491 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@776aec5c] to prepare test instance [com.javasampleapproach.springrest.mysql.SpringRestMySqlApplicationTests@796d3c9f]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
```

but I did not even use or import org.postgresql.Driver for nothing, I use MySQL.

.gitlab-ci.yml template that i added is:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
---
# Build JAVA applications using Apache Maven (http://maven.apache.org)
# For docker image tags see https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/
#
# For general lifecycle information see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
#
# This template will build and test your projects as well as create the documentation.
#
# * Caches downloaded dependencies and plugins between invocation.
# * Verify but don't deploy merge requests.
# * Deploy built artifacts from master branch only.
# * Shows how to use multiple jobs in test stage for verifying functionality
#   with multiple JDKs.
# * Uses site:stage to collect the documentation for multi-module projects.
# * Publishes the documentation for `master` branch.

variables:
  # This will supress any download for dependencies and plugins or upload messages which would clutter the console log.
  # `showDateTime` will show the passed time in milliseconds. You need to specify `--batch-mode` to make this work.
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  # As of Maven 3.3.0 instead of this you may define these options in `.mvn/maven.config` so the same config is used
  # when running from the command line.
  # `installAtEnd` and `deployAtEnd` are only effective with recent version of the corresponding plugins.
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"

# Cache downloaded dependencies and plugins between builds.
# To keep cache across branches add 'key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"'
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

# This will only validate and compile stuff and run e.g. maven-enforcer-plugin.
# Because some enforcer rules might check dependency convergence and class duplications
# we use `test-compile` here instead of `validate`, so the correct classpath is picked up.
.validate: &validate
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test-compile'

# For merge requests do not `deploy` but only run `verify`.
# See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
.verify: &verify
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify site site:stage'
  except:
    - master

# Validate merge requests using JDK7
validate:jdk7:
  <<: *validate
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-7

# Validate merge requests using JDK8
validate:jdk8:
  <<: *validate
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

# Verify merge requests using JDK7
verify:jdk7:
  <<: *verify
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-7

# Verify merge requests using JDK8
verify:jdk8:
  <<: *verify
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8


# For `master` branch run `mvn deploy` automatically.
# Here you need to decide whether you want to use JDK7 or 8.
# To get this working you need to define a volume while configuring your gitlab-ci-multi-runner.
# Mount your `settings.xml` as `/root/.m2/settings.xml` which holds your secrets.
# See https://maven.apache.org/settings.html
deploy:jdk8:
  # Use stage test here, so the pages job may later pickup the created site.
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy site site:stage'
  only:
    - master
  # Archive up the built documentation site.
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/staging
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8


pages:
  image: busybox:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    # Because Maven appends the artifactId automatically to the staging path if you did define a parent pom,
    # you might need to use `mv target/staging/YOUR_ARTIFACT_ID public` instead.
    - mv target/staging public
  dependencies:
    - deploy:jdk8
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
    - master
```

on my local environment i usually do:
to start backend:

```
mvn clean install
spring-boot:run
```

to start frontend:

```
ng serve
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: and what do your properties/yml look like?

Comment: i think don´t have his one..

Comment: The question looks too ambiguous, maybe try to split it in more specific questions. You are asking for `gitlab-ci` but you have an exception in HikariCP !